# Accessing RecyclerView.Adapter data in ViewHolder Inner class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My application involves tracking of vehicle movement through check gates. The gate id is passed on onNavigationItemSelected method after clicking the menuitem in NavigationView:-

```
          case R.id.gate_two:
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VehicleActivity.class);
                            intent2.putExtra(VehicleActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, 2);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                            finish();
                            break;
```

The gate id is passed to the VehicleFragment and retreived as below:

```
public class VehicleFragment extends Fragment {
private int gate;
private static String passvehicle_url = "http://192.168.123.123:8080/test/pass_vehicle.php";
private static String vehicle_url = "http://192.168.123.123:8080/test/track_vehicle.php";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    gate = getArguments().getInt("gate");
    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext(),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;
}
```

I am accessing gate id in ContentAdapter by passing a VehicleFragment object in the constructor:

```
public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int LENGTH=1 ;
    private int gate_id=0 ;
    private final String[] vehicles ;
    private final String[] vehicle_type ;        
    VehicleFragment vf;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, VehicleFragment vf) {                        
        this.vf = vf;
        gate_id = vf.gate;

        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(vehicle_url);
```

Now I need to access the gate id in the ViewHolder static inner class which I am unable to do. The vehicle will be passed through the gate on clicking the pass button

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView vehicles;
        public TextView vehicle_type;            
        public Button pass;

        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_status, parent, false));

            vehicles = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_no);
            vehicle_type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_type);                
            pass = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pass_vehicle);
            pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(passvehicle_url);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        con.setDoInput(true);
                        con.setDoOutput(true);
                        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                                .appendQueryParameter("timecard_no", timecard_no.getText().toString())
                                .appendQueryParameter("gate_id", id will be passed here );
```

Please suggest on how to resolve the issue and also on the design of the claases.

Comment: why you have declare `ViewHolder` as static?

Comment: Make inner class as non-static Inner class .

Comment: If you have just hover on the error the IDE will show the reason . But did not check that i guess .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove static keyword from class `ViewHolder`

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

to

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

Else change gate_id to static

```
private static int gate_id=0 ;
```

then you can directly access the gate_id